# Is it possible to use type in a function called from parent function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to call a function inside another function and use its type parameter as "default" type when calling child function.

Is it possible in Typescript?

```
// Parent interface
interface IParent {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

// Child interface with foreign key
interface IChild {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    ParentId: number;
}

// Parent function declaration:
function select<T>(query: {
    select: string,
    join: string,
}) {
    return `${query.select} ${query.join}`;
}

// Child function declaration (F type is optional):
function buildJoin<T, F = Record<any, any>>(foreignKey: keyof T, otherColumn: keyof F): string {
    return 'JOIN f on t.foreignKey = f.otherColumn';
}

// Strong typing:
select<IParent>({
    select: 'select * from Parent',
    join: buildJoin<IChild, IParent>('ParentId', 'id'), // explicitly typed "ParentType"
});

// Requested behaviour:
select<IParent>({
    select: 'select * from Parent',
    join: buildJoin<IChild>('ParentId', 'id'), // if 2nd type parameter omitted it should be taken from parent function
});
```

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAUEMCcFMDsAuoCWTbQGaQMawFBqIbZ6gCSUcSoA3vqI6gCYBco8ArgLYBGGAbgZN4kbrHYBnRNDQBzIQF98+EKADCACxQAbZqnRZcsUAHcUiTaEwB7OCjnxQAa1gBPQodInyW3fvomFnYuPkFhRlFxKRl5ISCqBERyNg4efmglFTVEmkxOeBxEFBsnZlgcHRhIYtLWfHzC2qdJWB0KxAAeABUAPgAKAEdODDd2QKZW9qKY2Xg5ABoI0AArGzRZ+SXFAEo6ZbhETmgnAAMAElph0YA6KY7FUEvr6DcbtbRFU6zVMD89awFIolMoVKrQGog0D9ABioEQbgADiYUJJQDZEc1IDodvVGsDSqBeJx-AApdbwHoLUBwgC8oAAShU7MxOpB4G5qey3L0BrZ7I4ANLudiuNw2TCgbrUmyWDDqGw6HjwUXuCU03GgaRzOT7IKHY5OADkpIA8uQAHLWdFORA3fmwBzwYVuUD0zA3WWaeWK5VGn5qADKMlKuoRiPk9XuRU6lBgSQGE0Y0cQ7CNKdAACprNAbNwIPGkEalkEPiqiSS9OS0LH-sxqXHqIgBkbcslmMXQEaUB2dtS1LAAB6InQoHAWHSu8OwfQAIjb3SRsFn+F2Ql+jNg12kM6JsE0kAAbiVjlG2h1Y23E8sU2mM9nMLn823i8sy+xiWSKbXtHoW22Uk7bte37MAUElAAmeB9GnUBEWqcRiGgdFuAsYh9AsVA0UQSBXCcR88zgwtkHxZpVx2IQgA)

Comment: You would have to structure it differently.  You are trying to derive the second type based on *where* the function is called.  But `buildJoin` is a top-level function and doesn't know or care that it is called inside the arguments of a `select<IParent>`.

Comment: As @LindaPaiste said, you can't do it from the context of the call to `buildJoin`. You might consider a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) instead, then `join` could be a method on what `select` returns, which means it can have access to the type parameter.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, that's exactly what I was envisioning!  You beat me to writing it :)  My version: https://tsplay.dev/W4XgOW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to infer a type argument to `buildJoin` based on where it's called, which you can't do. So in that sense, the answer to your question is "no."

As an alternative, you might write a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) in which `select` returns an object with a `join` method, which can then inherit the type parameter's value. Here's a rough example (not intended to be an actual robust implementation [though it does work for this limited example], just an example):

```js
// Parent interface
interface IParent {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

// Child interface with foreign key
interface IChild {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    ParentId: number;
}

// Parent function declaration:
function select<ParentType>(select: string) {
    return {
        query: select,
        join<ChildType>(foreignKey: keyof ChildType, otherColumn: keyof ParentType) {
            this.query += "\nJOIN f on t.foreignKey = f.otherColumn";
            return this;
        },
        build() {
            return this.query;
        },
    };
}

// Strong typing:
const sql = select<IParent>("select * from Parent")
    .join<IChild>("ParentId", "id")
    .build();
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 1):

There is another option relying on tagged primitive types, currying and function composition.

```js
const select = <Parent>(select: string) =>
    select as string & { _parent: Parent };

const join = <Child>(foreignKey: keyof Child) => <Parent>(otherColumn: keyof Parent) =>
    (select: string & { _parent: Parent }) =>
        `${select}\nJOIN f on t.foreignKey = f.otherColumn`;
```

You can use it like so

```js
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/function'

const ok1 = pipe(
    select <IParent>("select * from Parent"),
    join <IChild>("ParentId") ("id")
)

const ok2 = pipe(
    select <IParent>("select * from Parent"),
    join <IChild>("ParentId") <IParent>("id")
)
```

[plyaground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzmYYCmcC+cBmUIhwDkOYAtDAM4D0ANsAEbU4CuAdgMYzARtEBQ-atTgAFAIZQ0beMBlooOcRzT85MBUpVwAkhKkzE-OCbjAAJgC44bFiAYKA3MdNtxINNcowocgObOmILCcADCABbAtOZm8orKGADuwDDhuNBowH5scADWaACeanFaGDoRUTEILiYW1rb2TjU27p5w3r5sAc360jA6VjZ2DlCBghy83u1otGhccAC8cAA8vTIAfAAUlDNzMF4+-gCUi+vNO7Pz4pTth11wAGSIcAD6YJJ91mvwQaZw-BM2FMAFYQOSLFYVaJbHAZLJsADShWs+QKEBwYUi0ROC3WK2+WwgqQUoQgtDsbBRhXRYg+MhxZz+212XAOnT8j2ebzp+1pBh+DOafwABgASBAXPaYAA6bAAUgB5HQAOVwcF4cBgADpYVJ4UiChCcFqieESWSKcLnADJvAILkAIwQlDoTbnFnwZZ6HlbABEkvmACpcPhCN9fUcADTNUHgr1Q8x+74DCNwTa+iwR-hHca29W5ABMztQaDdfwDnu9-L9FbgwbwBD5fQj0b+sZy8axifTyfMqa9BPTmZzOZtQPgCigTqWLtL7su8HTtfroabMhbzRCAAEqGQ0AAPdBcPdQfBQawgYCUSj+FZVvqM0ztoudypJnkpk5Dvsj3PjuCTkWM4lmWpjbruB5HjAJ5nheV43vcA4+vOexLh6dYho24ZRjGYIduUXbvvyn53oOGY-tm-BAA)

Answer (score -1):

yes it is possible.
By calling the super() method in the constructor method, we call the parent's constructor method and gets access to the parent's properties and methods. Inheritance is useful for code reusability: reuse properties and methods of an existing class when you create a new class.